# Defining a newenviroment for definition, theorem, example and so on by using a name

Tags: environments

My trying of defining a `newenviroment` for LaTeX is

```
\usepackage{mdframed} 
\newenvironment{mf}{\begin{mdframed}}%
{\end{mdframed}}
```

I want to define a simple command with a name next to it, for example

`\begin{mf}[Definition 1.1] A paramatrized ...... \end{mf}` instead of writing

`\begin{mf}\textbf{Definition 1.1} A paramatrized ...... \end{mf}`

which would look like this

[image: Example]

Note that the name doesn't have to be a definition (in order to avoid using `\newenvironment{definition}[Definition]`) - but just a name for anything I could name. My problem is I can not add a code that allows me to write the way I want as explained above. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to specify the title in `[]` you need to define the `\newenvironment` to accept one parameter (`[1]`) and that it is optional defaulting to being empty ( the `[]` following the `[1]`):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
 
\newenvironment{mf}[1][]{\begin{mdframed}\textbf{#1}}%
{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mf}[Definition 1.1] A paramatrized ...... \end{mf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It was so similar to what I have tried when adding a code without using an extra part `[]` before I asked for help. I understand better now. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @AjmalW: This is the same for `\newcommand`s as well.

Comment: Could you please help me with a short code? I would like to define `\mathbb{R}^{m}` into $\bb{R}[m]$? I could define `\mathbb{R}` into `\bb{R}` by using `newcommand{\bb}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}`. It looks wrong with `newcommand{\bb}[1][2][]{\mathbb{#1}^{#2}}`.

Comment: @AjmalW: Putting optional parameters at the end is not quite so straight forward, but can be done (requires `xparse`). Best if you posted a new question.